# nopcommerce 3.40 deployment 403 error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nopcommerce

If i compile and deploy the nopCommerce 3.40, it works fine on my website and takes me directly to the install.

If i install nopCommerce on my localhost and attach it to a local DB, then compile and deploy I get a 403.

I want to make changes to the source code.  So I need to install so i can see the changes and debug them before I deploy.  Do I need to reset the install some how?  Im not sure what to do.

I am following the deploy instructions in all cases, which are.  Rebuild and deploy in release mode.  On a side note. Im using VS2013 and if I deploy in Release - Any Cpu, I get errors.  I can only successfully publish in : Release - x86

EDIT:
Ok, I only get the errors in Release mode build: as follows below
[image]

EDIT 2:
I read some stuff on another forum.  It looks like I need to upblock these files.  Im not sure how to do it in Windows explorer under properties on win8.1

EDIT 3:  Ok Nevermind the unblock thing.  When i build in release mode im getting a bunch more errors.  VStudio is looking for a bunch of .dll's in the release bin folders.  The dlls are not in the folder.  Not sure if I should put them in their or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear and then re-build the entire solution in VS

Comment: I assume your talking about Clean solution?